# Excel 2010 VBA transfer multicolumn Listbox to named range

Tags: vba, excel, listbox, excel-2010

I've got a sub which I want to use to copy items from a multicolumn listbox to a named range on a spreadsheet. The part of the sub I'm having trouble with is commented as "Transfer to table" (below). It's not copying to my named range ("Import_Items" or "Export_Items", which reference certain tables depending on which sheet is being used as the source), and instead is copying to row 1 starting with column C. I feel like I'm probably missing something very simple, any help would be appreciated.

```
Sub Transfer()
Dim CopyToWB As Workbook
Dim ASName As String
Dim lItem As Long, lRows As Long, lCols As Long
Dim lColLoop As Long, lTransferRow As Long

Set CopyToWB = Workbooks.Open(FPath & "\" & FName)
ASName = ActiveSheet.Name
lRows = ItemsLB.ListCount - 1
lCols = ItemsLB.ColumnCount - 1

With CopyToWB.Sheets(ASName)
    Range(ASName & "_Date") = DateTB
    Range(ASName & "_Tool_Order") = ToolOrderTB
    Range(ASName & "_WAY_BILL") = TrackingTB
    Range(ASName & "_TPOC_Name") = TPOCNameTB
    Range(ASName & "_Site") = SiteTB
    Range(ASName & "_Street") = StreetTB
    Range(ASName & "_City_State") = CityStateTB
    Range(ASName & "_Zip") = ZipTB
    Range(ASName & "_SPOC_Name") = SPOCNameTB
    Range(ASName & "_SPOC_Phone") = PhoneTB
    Range(ASName & "_SPOC_Email") = SPOCEmailTB
    Range(ASName & "_TPOC_Email") = TPOCEmailTB


    'Transfer to table
    With Range(ASName & "_Items", ActiveSheet.Cells(lRows + 1, 4 + lCols)) 'Transfer to range
        For lItem = 0 To lRows
            'Increment variable for row transfer range
            lTransferRow = lTransferRow + 1
              'Loop through columns of selected row
              For lColLoop = 0 To lCols
                 'Transfer selected row to relevant row of transfer range
                 .Cells(lTransferRow, lColLoop + 1) = ItemsLB.List(lItem, lColLoop)
              Next lColLoop
        Next
    End With

    'Export/Import-dependent
    If ASName = "Export" Then
        Range(ASName & "_TPOC_Print_Name") = TPOCNameTB
        Range(ASName & "_TPOC_Title") = TPOCTitleTB
    ElseIf ASName = "Import" Then
        Range(ASName & "_Consignee_Name_Number") = TPOCNameTB & _
            " - " & TPOCPhoneTB
    End If

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    .SaveAs FPath & FName

    'Optional export to PDF
    If PDFChkBx = True Then
        ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat _
            Type:=xlTypePDF, _
            Filename:=FPath & "Proforma Customs Invoice " & ToolOrderTB.Value & ".pdf", _
            Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
            IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
            IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
            OpenAfterPublish:=True
    End If

    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End With
```

End Sub

Comment: Why loop rather than just dropping the `List` array into the sheet?

Comment: It's modified from a thread I found on OzGrid, I've been having trouble getting anything to copy to a table with other subs/userforms so I tried it this way. Can you give an example of what might be a better way to do it?

Comment: meant to comment to your answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how to drop the entire list into a range in one go:

```
With Me.ItemsLB
    Range(ASName & "_Items").Resize(.ListCount, .ColumnCount).Value = .List
End With
```

Here's an example to explicitly resize the table:

```
Dim lo As ListObject

With Me.ItemsLB
    Set lo = Range(ASName & "_Items").ListObject
    lo.Resize lo.Range.Resize(.ListCount + 1, .ColumnCount)
    lo.DataBodyRange.Value = .List
End With
```

Comment: Are you kidding me. All the stuff I've been looking up, trying to figure out why it wouldn't just *work* and it took something so simple. Thank you.

Comment: Incidentally, is there a similar way to drop the listitems into the table itself? Right now I'm using the named range which refers to the table, and all attempts in the past to copy straight to the table failed. The code you provided worked, but I found that if my listitems outnumber the lines in the named range then the range doesn't resize itself. Thanks again!

Comment: Are you talking about an actual Table rather than a simple named range? A Table should simply expand to include the new data.

Comment: Right. My named ranges ("Export_Items" and "Import_Items") refer to tables EITable and IITable respectively. I've had issues getting values to paste directly into those tables, so instead I tried creating these named ranges which refer to the tables so I can drop values into them. Hopefully all that makes sense... Basically, if I could get rid of the named ranges and just go directly with the tables then that would be great, otherwise a way to resize the ranges/tables so my listitems don't run past the designated area.

Comment: I've updated the answer to show code to explicitly resize a table.

Comment: Alright, found an issue... If I only have one item in the list, I get `Run-time error '91': Object variable or with block variable not set`. Debug highlights `lo.DataBodyRange.Value = .List`. Any idea why? Thanks.